# Open new window with last remembered window size in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui

For a macOS app, I have the requirement of opening additional windows with the size the user changed the window to last to, albeit with a minimum size of 1280x800. I am controlling the size right now by specifying the frame like this:

```swift
.frame(minWidth: 1280.0, idealWidth: windowSizeWidth, minHeight: 800.0, idealHeight: windowSizeHeight)
```

I have the code in place to register the user's changes in size and storing them to `UserDefaults` with `@AppStorage` (in the variable `windowSizeHeight` and `windowSizeWidth` mentioned above).

Unfortunately though, on opening a **new** window with `Cmd + N`, I cannot seem to open these with the user's window size, but with the minimum size specified. The `UserDefaults` are read correctly, which I can see by printing the to the console, but it seems as though `minWidth` and `minHeight` are taking precedence over their `ideal` counterparts–which is not what I'd expect...

Is what I am trying to accomplish even possible?

Here's all the code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct so_RememberWindowSizeApp: App {
  @AppStorage("windowSizeHeight") var windowSizeHeight = 800.0
  @AppStorage("windowSizeWidth") var windowSizeWidth = 1280.0

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      Group {
        ContentView()
          .overlay {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
              Color.clear
                .onAppear {
                  print(" Startup Width: \(proxy.size.width), Startup Height: \(proxy.size.height)")
                }
                .onChange(of: proxy.size) { _, newValue in
                  windowSizeHeight = newValue.height
                  windowSizeWidth = newValue.width

                  print(" New Width: \(windowSizeWidth), New Height: \(windowSizeHeight)")
                }
            }
          }
          .frame(minWidth: 1280.0, idealWidth: windowSizeWidth, minHeight: 800.0, idealHeight: windowSizeHeight)
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @AppStorage("windowSizeHeight") var windowSizeHeight = 800.0
  @AppStorage("windowSizeWidth") var windowSizeWidth = 1280.0

  var body: some View {
    Group {
      let _ = Self._printChanges()
      VStack(spacing: 32.0) {
        Text("Current Height in UserDefaults: \(windowSizeHeight)")
        Text("Current Width in UserDefaults: \(windowSizeWidth)")
      }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // grab available space
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideal sizes in SwiftUI work differently than it may seem. Given min or max constraints preceede over ideal.
[`frame` from Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/frame(minWidth:idealWidth:maxWidth:minHeight:idealHeight:maxHeight:alignment:)):

> The size proposed to this view is the size proposed to the frame, limited by any constraints specified, and with any ideal dimensions specified replacing any corresponding unspecified dimensions in the proposal.

But there’s [`fixedSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fixedsize()):

> Fixes this view at its ideal size.

So replace your frame modifier  in app struct with this:

```
.frame(idealWidth: windowSizeWidth, idealHeight: windowSizeHeight)
.fixedSize()
```

And remove the frame modifier in ContentView.

You can find an in-depth explanation [in this article](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-fixedsize/#what-is-an-ideal-size).

Comment: Sorry for my late reply during the holiday season... Unfortunately, I do not want to specify a fixed size because that would result in the user not being able to resize at all. On the other hand, since there has not been any other answer and I don't want to loose the bounty to the system, I will grant it to you.